# When I try to curl using internal ip it works but the same doesn't work with external ip on GCP?

Tags: jenkins, networking, google-cloud-platform

I'm bit new to GCP, I am trying to run a curl command using internal ip this works but when tried with external ip it doesn't response

```
    curl -vvvv http://10.128.0.3:50000
* Rebuilt URL to: http://10.128.0.3:50000/
*   Trying 10.128.0.3...
* Connected to 10.128.0.3 (10.128.0.3) port 50000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.128.0.3:50000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< 
Jenkins-Agent-Protocols: JNLP4-connect, Ping
Jenkins-Version: 2.121.3
Jenkins-Session: 4c0a93f0
Client: 10.128.0.3
Server: 10.128.0.3
Remoting-Minimum-Version: 2.60
* Closing connection 0

curl -vvvv http://35.232.33.183:50000
* Rebuilt URL to: http://35.232.33.183:50000/
*   Trying 35.232.33.183...
```

Comment: Are all the firewall rules correctly configured?

Comment: yes , it allows ssh, http, https

Comment: Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
To                         Action      From
8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
50000                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
50000 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

Comment: Are you running curl from the same VM, a different VM on the same network, a pod in a k8s cluster, a VM on a different network, a vm in a different project, from a host  outside GCP, or from somewhere else?

Comment: WilliamPursell i am running command from the same vm.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that the firewall is properly configured by running the ff:
telnet 35.232.33.183 50000

You should get a prompt (which exact prompt depends on the remote server's OS.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to expose your internal IP to external world using tools like ngrok. Use the following steps to install and run ngrok. (This example is for Ubuntnu 16.04 on GCP and should work on other platforms too)

The following instructions are for using ngrok to expose localhost application to
internet. This is tested on CGP, Ubuntu 16.04

Step 1: **Download ngrok**

Login into https://ngrok.com/ and download Linux(32-bit) zip file to your google
instance (you may choose the right version for your platform else you will get a segmentation fault while trying to execute)

Step 2: **Unzip executable**

mkdir ngrok

cd ngrok

unzip ngrok-stable-linux-386.zip

Step 3: **Run your app**

Run your app which is listening on port 5000 of localhost.

Python3 main.py

The output will look like this:

name@instance-1:~$ python3 main.py

- Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 279-195-470

Your app is now listening on port 5000 of the local machine

Step 4: **Run ngrok**

For exposing an app listening on port 5000, run the following command

./ngrok http 5000

The output will look like this:

ngrok by @inconshreveable (Ctrl+C to quit)

Session Status online

Session Expires 7 hours, 59 minutes

Version 2.2.8 Region United States (us)

Web Interface http://127.0.0.1:4040

Forwarding http://f985f882.ngrok.io -> localhost:5000

Forwarding https://f985f882.ngrok.io -> localhost:5000

Connections ttl opn rt1 rt5 p50 p90 0 0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

Step 5: **Test your app**

Run this command:

curl http://f985f882.ngrok.io

The output will look like:

Mynames-MacBook-Pro:~ Myname$ curl http://f985f882.ngrok.io

I am running

You can also access the above url from any browser

**In conclusion**

ngrok is very simple and easy tool to use